# How to parse local JSON data in Swift?

Tags: json, swift, parsing, bundle

How to parse local JSON data **where nested (optional) property is same as main.**

Items data may be available or may not be available.

```
struct Category: Identifiable, Codable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let image: String
    var items: [Category]?   
}
```

I am using common Bundle extension to parse JSON data.

```
extension Bundle {

    func decode<T: Codable>(_ file: String) -> T {
        guard let url = self.url(forResource: file, withExtension: nil) else {
            fatalError("Failed to locate \(file) in bundle.")
        }

        guard let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) else {
            fatalError("Failed to load \(file) from bundle.")
        }

        let decoder = JSONDecoder()

        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "y-MM-dd"
        decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(formatter)
    
        guard let loaded = try? decoder.decode(T.self, from: data) else {
            fatalError("Failed to decode \(file) from bundle.")
        }
        return loaded
    }
}
```

For eg data :

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Apple",
        "image": "img_url",
        "items" : [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "iPhone",
                "image": "img_url",
                "items" : [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "name": "iPhone 11 Pro",
                        "image": "img_url"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "name": "iPhone 11 Pro Max",
                        "image": "img_url"
                    }    
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "iPad",
                "image": "img_url",
                "items" : [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "name": "iPad mini",
                        "image": "img_url"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "name": "iPad Air",
                        "image": "img_url"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 3,
                        "name": "iPad Pro",
                        "image": "img_url"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Samsung",
        "image": "img_url",
        "items" : [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Phone",
                "image": "img_url"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Tablet",
                "image": "img_url"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nesting is not the issue here, You are facing an `Array` of `Content`s. so you should pass `[Content]` to the `decoder` like:

```
let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
try! jsonDecoder.decode([Category].self, from: json)
```

---

## Property Wrapper

You can implement a simple property wrapper for loading and decoding all of your properties:

```
@propertyWrapper struct BundleFile<DataType: Decodable> {
    let name: String
    let type: String = "json"
    let fileManager: FileManager = .default
    let bundle: Bundle = .main
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()

    var wrappedValue: DataType {
        guard let path = bundle.path(forResource: name, ofType: type) else { fatalError("Resource not found") }
        guard let data = fileManager.contents(atPath: path) else { fatalError("File not loaded") }
        return try! decoder.decode(DataType.self, from: data)
    }
}
```

Now you can have any property that should be loaded from a file in a `Bundle` like:

```
@BundleFile(name: "MyFile")
var contents: [Content]
```

<sub>Note that since the property should be loaded from the bundle, I raised a `FatalError`. Because the only person should be responsible for these errors is the developer at the code time (not the run time).</sub>

Comment: Thank you so much. I was wasted almost 2 days to solve. @propertyWrapper is like magic...! Thank you 

Comment: I am using this response in nested expand/collapse list which is available in iOS 14 beta 3. eg. https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-create-expanding-lists by Paul Hudson. List behaviour is different. Can you help me out for that?

Comment: Yes I can, but not in the comments section of this unrelated question. Maybe you should workaround it and of the issue persists, ask a new question about that `SwiftUI`'s `List` ;)

Comment: It because of id. If id is same for nested items, collapse that all same id. Fixed by changing to unique id, nested also.